# Parsing a website, saving tables in Excel

Tags: performance, vba, excel, web-scraping

This program parses a website. The program works well, but is too long. I want to simplify/speed it up.

How program works:

1. First , the program finds needed  hyperlink in Excel
2. Then by the hyperlink , the program goes to the site , where it finds a certain table of elements. Then it takes out the "href" of each element , turns it into a hyperlink , and inserts it into Excel in the first table
3. Then again by the hyperlink , the program goes to the site, where it finds a certain table of elements. Then  it extracts the text of each element and inserts it into Excel in the second table
4. Then it goes through the elements of the 1st and 2nd tables , so that in the 3rd table each element contains a "hyperlink +text"

```
Sub Softãèïåðññûëêè()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False


Call mainìàññèâû

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub


Sub mainìàññèâû()
Dim r As Range
Dim firstAddress As String
Dim iLoop As Long
Dim book1 As Workbook
Dim sheetNames(1 To 19) As String
Dim Ssilka As String

  '!!! 1.  First , the program finds needed  hyperlink


  sheetNames(1) = "Ëèñò1"
  sheetNames(2) = "Ëèñò2"
  sheetNames(3) = "Ëèñò3"
  sheetNames(4) = "Ëèñò4"
  sheetNames(5) = "Ëèñò5"
   sheetNames(6) = "Ëèñò6"
  sheetNames(7) = "Ëèñò7"
  sheetNames(8) = "Ëèñò8"
  sheetNames(9) = "Ëèñò9"
  sheetNames(10) = "Ëèñò10"
  sheetNames(11) = "Ëèñò11"
  sheetNames(12) = "Ëèñò12"
  sheetNames(13) = "Ëèñò13"
  sheetNames(14) = "Ëèñò14"
  sheetNames(15) = "Ëèñò15"
  sheetNames(16) = "Ëèñò16"
  sheetNames(17) = "Ëèñò17"
  sheetNames(18) = "Ëèñò18"
  sheetNames(19) = "Ëèñò19"



 Set book1 = Workbooks.Open("E:\Super M\Ïðîåêò ñòàâêè\Ïîèñê ðåøåíèÿ\Óñîâ 7\Óñëîâèÿ äëÿ àíäåðäîãîâ\6.xlsm")

 iLoop = -1

 With book1.Worksheets("Ëèñò1").Range("R34:R99")

 For Each r In .Rows
     If r.Value = 1 Then

        iLoop = iLoop + 1
        Ssilka = r.Offset(, -13).Hyperlinks.Item(1).Address
        .Parent.Parent.Worksheets(sheetNames(1)).Activate
        .Parent.Parent.Save
        extractTable Ssilka, book1, iLoop

      End If
   Next r

End With
book1.Save
book1.Close
Exit Sub


End Sub


Function extractTable(Ssilka As String, book1 As Workbook, iLoop As Long)
Dim oDom As Object, oTable As Object, oRow As Object
Dim iRows As Integer, iCols As Integer
Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
Dim data()
Dim oHttp As Object
Dim oRegEx As Object
Dim sResponse As String
Dim oRange As Range
Dim Perem1 As String
Dim Perem2 As String



   '!!!2.  Then by the hyperlink , the program goes to the site , where it finds a certain table of elements.Then it takes out the "href" of each element , turns it into a hyperlink , and inserts it into Excel in the 1-st table

' get page
Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
oHttp.Open "GET", Ssilka, False
oHttp.Send

' cleanup response
sResponse = StrConv(oHttp.responseBody, vbUnicode)
Set oHttp = Nothing

sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))

Set oRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With oRegEx
.MultiLine = True
.Global = True
.IgnoreCase = False
.Pattern = "<(script|SCRIPT)[\w\W]+?</\1>"
sResponse = .Replace(sResponse, "")
End With
Set oRegEx = Nothing

 ' create Document from response
 Set oDom = CreateObject("htmlFile")
 oDom.Write sResponse
 DoEvents

 ' table with results, indexes starts with zero
  Set oTable = oDom.getelementsbytagname("table")(3)

DoEvents

iRows = oTable.Rows.Length
iCols = oTable.Rows(1).Cells.Length

' first row and first column contain no intresting data
ReDim data(1 To iRows - 1, 1 To iCols - 1)

' fill in data array
For x = 1 To iRows - 1
Set oRow = oTable.Rows(x)

For y = 1 To iCols - 1
     If oRow.Cells(y).Children.Length > 0 Then
        data(x, y) = oRow.Cells(y).getelementsbytagname("a")(0).getattribute("href")

    End If

Next y
Next x

Set oRow = Nothing
Set oTable = Nothing
Set oDom = Nothing

 ' put data array on worksheet

 Set oRange = book1.ActiveSheet.Cells(110, 26 + (iLoop * 21)).Resize(iRows - 1, iCols - 1)
oRange.NumberFormat = "@"
oRange.Value = data
oRange.Replace What:="about:", Replacement:="http://allscores.ru/soccer/"
Set oRange = Nothing

   '!!!! 3.  Then again by the hyperlink , the program goes to the site , where it finds a certain table of elements. Then  it extracts the text of each element and inserts it into Excel in the 2-nd table

  ' get page
   Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
   oHttp.Open "GET", Ssilka, False
   oHttp.Send

   ' cleanup response
   sResponse = StrConv(oHttp.responseBody, vbUnicode)
   Set oHttp = Nothing

   sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))

   Set oRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With oRegEx
.MultiLine = True
.Global = True
.IgnoreCase = False
.Pattern = "<(script|SCRIPT)[\w\W]+?</\1>"
sResponse = .Replace(sResponse, "")
End With
Set oRegEx = Nothing

 ' create Document from response
Set oDom = CreateObject("htmlFile")
oDom.Write sResponse
DoEvents

' table with results, indexes starts with zero
Set oTable = oDom.getelementsbytagname("table")(3)

DoEvents

iRows = oTable.Rows.Length
iCols = oTable.Rows(1).Cells.Length

' first row and first column contain no intresting data
ReDim data(1 To iRows - 1, 1 To iCols - 1)

' fill in data array
For x = 1 To iRows - 1
Set oRow = oTable.Rows(x)

 For y = 1 To iCols - 1
     If oRow.Cells(y).Children.Length > 0 Then
        data(x, y) = oRow.Cells(y).innerText

    End If

Next y
Next x

Set oRow = Nothing
Set oTable = Nothing
Set oDom = Nothing

' put data array on worksheet

Set oRange = book1.ActiveSheet.Cells(185, 26 + (iLoop * 21)).Resize(iRows - 1, iCols - 1)
oRange.NumberFormat = "@"
oRange.Value = data

Set oRange = Nothing

 '!!! 4.  Then it goes through the elements of the 1-st and 2-nd tables , so that in the 3-rd table each element contains a "hyperlink +text"


 For A = 0 To 4
 For B = 0 To 65

 Perem1 = book1.ActiveSheet.Cells(110 + B, (26 + (iLoop * 21)) + A).Value
 Perem2 = book1.ActiveSheet.Cells(185 + B, (26 + (iLoop * 21)) + A).Value

  book1.ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(34 + B, (26 + (iLoop * 21)) + A), Address:=Perem1, TextToDisplay:=Perem2
  Next
  Next



  End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Having consistent indentation will help readability. Declaring your variables closer to where they are used also helps clear things up, `firstAddress` isn't used anywhere.

---

Using Alt+D+L (Debug>Compile) brings attention to the variables `A` and `B` not being declared anywhere. Alt+T+O (Tools>Options) and making sure `Require Variable Declaration` is enabled will have future-you thanking current-you. Not having variable explicitly declared makes debugging needlessly harder.

---

Variables that are declared as `Integer` are converted to a `Long`, better to initially declare them as `Long`.

---

`extractTable` is a function but nothing is being returned. Functions have a value returned `Public Function Foo(ByVal bar as long) as <Type>`. The function is assigned to what it is returning `set Foo = wb1.Range("A1:B2")` or `Foo = 9999` depending on whether it's an object or not. `extractTable` should be a `Sub`

---

Using the `Value` property on a `Range` object can cause rounding issues (A little reading: https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/text-vs-value-vs-value2-slow-text-and-how-to-avoid-it/).

---

Magic numbers. In your code you have the values of `110`, `185`, `26`, `21`, `34`, `-13` that are doing things which aren't arbitrary. They are there for a purpose, but what purpose? Numbers don't mean a lot so use a `Const` constant to describe what they are doing. Again naming is hard and you'll have to figure out how to best name them. `110` may become `Private Const getAttributePopulationRow As Long = 110`.

---

The above covers the easiest stuff.

Instead of having 1 big Method that does several things it's preferable to have it do 1 thing. This reduces cognitive load and how much you have to remember at an given time. Imagine the below code. Seeing that is much easier to understand what's going on than remembering what 300+ lines of code is supposed to be doing.

```
Sub Foo()
    CreateATable
    ManipulateATable
    SaveTableInNewWorkbook "C:\SpecificPath\", "Filename.xlsm"
End Sub
```

---

Comments `'!!!2,3,4` that's describing what you're doing indicates to me that's a new method trying to escape. Code should be self documenting, it should tell you what it's doing by reading it. Comments should describe *why* it's being done that way. After doing this kind of refactoring `extractTable` becomes.

```
Private Sub extractTable(Ssilka As String, book1 As Workbook, iLoop As Long)
    TablePart2 Ssilka, iLoop, book1
    TablePart3 Ssilka, iLoop, book1
    TablePart4 iLoop, book1
End Sub
```

Once that's done and you compare `TablePart2` and `TablePart3` you can see they are virtually identical.

When writing code you want to follow DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself), no copy/pasting. Copy/pasting leads to less maintainable code and makes it harder to ensure you've updated errors because you have to go to every place and update accordingly. By making the solution generic and then applying the generic solution to your specific concern you make the code much more reusable.

---

Looking at `TablePart2` what is it doing? Doing some HTTP request, cleaning, getting a table and populating it on a range.  Naming is hard and you have to figure it out. I'm not entirely sure what to name it, for now I'll use `PopulateTable`.

Where there are differences in this process you'll see they vary by the population of `data(x, y)` and where you set `oRange` starting from (and the `oRange.Replace()` call). Supplying an argument to the parameter will allow you to take care of this making the code more generic.

```
Public SomeMethod(ByVal suppliedParameter as string)
```

The above describes the method signature. What it accepts as a parameter.
Below is how it's used, and the argument that's supplied

```
SomeMethod "suppliedArgument"
```

---

What comes from an initial refactoring `Private Sub TablePart2(ByVal Ssilka As String, ByVal iLoop As Long, ByVal book1 As Workbook)` and `TablePart3` become `Private Sub PopulateTable(ByVal populateFrom as DataFrom, ByVal Ssilka As String, ByVal iLoop As Long, ByVal book1 As Workbook)`.

You'll see that the first parameter `populateFrom` uses a parameter that's defined by an `Enum` (enumeration).

```
Private Enum DataFrom
    InnerText
    GetAttribute
End Enum
```

This Enum will allow you to explicitly specify what want to use.

Now inside of `PopulateTable` you check on `populateFrom` and make decisions based on that. What follows is the refactoring of the code I was able to do.

---

Cleaned up code.

```
Option Explicit

Private Enum DataFrom
    InnerText
    GetAttribute
End Enum

Private Const getAttributePopulationRow As Long = 110
Private Const innerTextPopulationRow As Long = 185
Private Const columnOffsetMultiple As Long = 21
Private Const columnOffset As Long = 26

Sub Softãèïåðññûëêè()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Call mainìàññèâû
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

Private Sub mainìàññèâû()

    Dim sheetNames(1 To 19) As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(sheetNames) To UBound(sheetNames)
        sheetNames(i) = "Ëèñò" & i
    Next

    Dim book1 As Workbook
    Set book1 = Workbooks.Open("E:\Super M\Ïðîåêò ñòàâêè\Ïîèñê ðåøåíèÿ\Óñîâ 7\Óñëîâèÿ äëÿ àíäåðäîãîâ\6.xlsm")

    Dim iLoop As Long
    iLoop = -1

    With book1.Worksheets("Ëèñò1").Range("R34:R99")
        Dim r As Range
        For Each r In .Rows
            If r.Value = 1 Then
                iLoop = iLoop + 1

                Dim Ssilka As String
                Ssilka = r.Offset(, -13).Hyperlinks.Item(1).Address
                .Parent.Parent.Worksheets(sheetNames(1)).Activate
                .Parent.Parent.Save
                extractTable Ssilka, book1, iLoop
            End If
        Next r
    End With

    book1.Save
    book1.Close
    Exit Sub

End Sub

Private Sub extractTable(Ssilka As String, book1 As Workbook, iLoop As Long)
    PopulateTable GetAttribute, Ssilka, iLoop, book1
    PopulateTable InnerText, Ssilka, iLoop, book1
    TablePart4 iLoop, book1
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateTable(ByVal populateFrom As DataFrom, ByVal Ssilka As String, ByVal iLoop As Long, ByVal book1 As Workbook)
    ' get page
    Dim oHttp As Object
    Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    oHttp.Open "GET", Ssilka, False
    oHttp.Send

    ' cleanup response
    Dim sResponse As String
    sResponse = StrConv(oHttp.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    Set oHttp = Nothing

    sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))

    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .MultiLine = True
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "<(script|SCRIPT)[\w\W]+?</\1>"
        sResponse = .Replace(sResponse, "")
    End With

    ' create Document from response
    Dim oDom As Object
    Set oDom = CreateObject("htmlFile")
    oDom.Write sResponse
    DoEvents

    ' table with results, indexes starts with zero
    Dim oTable As Object
    Set oTable = oDom.getelementsbytagname("table")(3)

    DoEvents

    Dim iRows As Long
    iRows = oTable.Rows.Length
    Dim iCols As Long
    iCols = oTable.Rows(1).Cells.Length

    ' first row and first column contain no intresting data
    Dim data()
    ReDim data(1 To iRows - 1, 1 To iCols - 1)

    ' fill in data array
    Dim x As Long
    For x = 1 To iRows - 1
        Dim oRow As Object
        Set oRow = oTable.Rows(x)

        Dim y As Long
        For y = 1 To iCols - 1
            If oRow.Cells(y).Children.Length > 0 Then

                If populateFrom = GetAttribute Then
                    data(x, y) = oRow.Cells(y).getelementsbytagname("a")(0).GetAttribute("href")
                ElseIf populateFrom = InnerText Then
                    data(x, y) = oRow.Cells(y).InnerText
                End If

            End If

        Next y
    Next x

    Set oRow = Nothing
    Set oTable = Nothing
    Set oDom = Nothing

    ' put data array on worksheet
    Dim startRow As Long
    If populateFrom = GetAttribute Then
        startRow = getAttributePopulationRow
    ElseIf populateFrom = InnerText Then
        startRow = innerTextPopulationRow
    End If

    With book1.ActiveSheet.Cells(startRow, columnOffset + (iLoop * columnOffsetMultiple)).Resize(iRows - 1, iCols - 1)
        .NumberFormat = "@"
        .Value = data

        If populateFrom = GetAttribute Then
            .Replace What:="about:", Replacement:="http://allscores.ru/soccer/"
        End If
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub TablePart4(ByVal iLoop As Long, ByVal book1 As Workbook)
    Const rowOffset As Long = 34

    Dim A As Long
    For A = 0 To 4
        Dim B As Long
        For B = 0 To 65

            Dim Perem1 As String
            Perem1 = book1.ActiveSheet.Cells(getAttributePopulationRow + B, (columnOffset + (iLoop * columnOffsetMultiple)) + A).Value2
            Dim Perem2 As String
            Perem2 = book1.ActiveSheet.Cells(innerTextPopulationRow + B, (columnOffset + (iLoop * columnOffsetMultiple)) + A).Value2

            book1.ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(rowOffset + B, (columnOffset + (iLoop * columnOffsetMultiple)) + A), Address:=Perem1, TextToDisplay:=Perem2
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

---

This simplifies the code. Now it's your turn to investigate how to speed it up.

Comment: Thanks for your work , but your simplifications only wins maximum 5 % of time . I need to win >80 % . And it is real , because >80% of time the program spend on getting data from website , pasting it in Excel ,replace every element , then doing same process with another data , then going throug two tables to create third table .But these processes are not simplified in any way .But this is the main goal .

Comment: There might be ways of improving the execution but without knowing the workbook contents I don't think there's much more that can be done.

Comment: how about recordset ?